# How to bind a scenario to a particular steps class in cucumber java

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Is there a way to bind a scenario to a steps class in cucumber. 
I want cucumber to look for the steps of a scenario in a particular class, instead of looking at all the steps in the package.

This is because I have common "Given" text for multiple tests, but the step code is different in all these cases. So I would like to bind the scenario to a class in which the steps of it are present.

Thanks

Comment: Are they in the same feature file?

Comment: Couple of scenarios in one feature file and the rest in another feature file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of for binding different scenarios, with the same wording, to different step implementations is to divide them into different packages.

Instead of doing that, I would encourage you to take a step back and ask yourself why you describe different parts of your system using the same words. How come you want different behaviour but still describe them in the same way? In what way are they really different?

The possibility to decide which step implementation each scenario should use is not available. The reason is that if you want to describe two different behaviours with the same words, then you have some ambiguity lurking in your implementation and you would like to find and fix that one rather than forcing a tool do a thing it doesn’t really support.

Answer (score 0):

Whikle I fully agree with @Thomas Sundberg regarding the ambiguity (if you're using the same words to describe essentially different behaviors what are your scenarios really communicating?), if you want to use different step definitions for different tests, you could specify different `glue` in your runner or run configuration.